How to swap configuration entities within config files?
I got two patterns identified through awk in the single file.
awk '/\[code\.change\..*\]/ {found=1; print; next} found && NF {print} found && !NF {exit}' filename
awk '/\[code\.test\..*\]/ {found=1; print; next} found && NF {print} found && !NF {exit}' filename

Is there a possibility I can combine these two awks in one to swap the blocks?
An example of the config file is below:
file.cfg
[code.change.1]
file.path=filename
file.contact=manager
file.active=TRUE

[code.test.1]
ls -la filepath
pwd
find . -name filename

I just need to swap the order of the configuration.

What is the content of the input file? What is your expected result?

The solution for a file containing just those 2 blank-line-separated blocks will be different from the solution for a file containing blockes before/after/between those blocks and/or with those blocks in either order so if the example provided so far isn't truly representative of your real input then please [edit] your question to fix it.

With the provided example, would you please try:
awk -v RS= '                                                            # records are reparated by blank lines
    /^\[code\.change/ {pos1 = NR}                                       # position of the 1st block
    /^\[code\.test/ {pos2 = NR}                                         # position of the 2nd block
    {
        ary[NR] = $0                                                    # store the record in an array
    }
    END {
        tmp = ary[pos1]; ary[pos1] = ary[pos2]; ary[pos2] = tmp         # swap the two records
        for (i = 1; i <= NR; i++) print(ary[i], i<NR ? ORS : "")        # print the array
    }
' file.cfg


Very good explanation and loved the approach of RS paragraph mode one. cheers.

If ed is availabe/acceptable, something like:
#!/bin/sh

ed -s file.cfg <<'EOF'
  /^$/m$                                                ##: Move the blank/empty line at the end
  /^\[code\.change\.1\]/;/^\[code\.test\.1\]/-1m$       ##: From [code.change.1] down to [code.test.1] minus 1 line move to the end
  ,p                                                    ##: Print the changes from the buffer only, Does not edit the file.
  Q                                                     ##: Exit/quit silently
EOF


In-one-line
printf '%s\n' '/^$/m$' '/^\[code\.change\.1\]/;/^\[code\.test\.1\]/-1m$' ,p Q | ed -s file.cfg


If you're satisfied with the output/outcome

Change Q to w if in_place editing is needed.

Remove the ,p to silence the output.

See POSIX ed

See GNU ed



Assuming the input is a file of just 2 blocks as shown in the example in the question, then using any awk:
$ awk -v RS= -v OFS='\n\n' '{v[NR]=$0} END{print v[2], v[1]}' file.cfg
[code.test.1]
ls -la filepath
pwd
find . -name filename

[code.change.1]
file.path=filename
file.contact=manager
file.active=TRUE

or:
$ awk -v RS= -v OFS='\n\n' 'NR==1{s=$0; next} {print $0, s}' file.cfg
[code.test.1]
ls -la filepath
pwd
find . -name filename

[code.change.1]
file.path=filename
file.contact=manager
file.active=TRUE

or with GNU awk for multi-char RS:
$ awk -v RS='^$' -F'\n\n' -v OFS='\n' '{print $2, $1}' file.cfg
[code.test.1]
ls -la filepath
pwd
find . -name filename

[code.change.1]
file.path=filename
file.contact=manager
file.active=TRUE

